# Swift, Add Custom Array in NSUserDefaults

Tags: caching, swift2

I am putting the custom array  in caching and try to fetch it from Key.

Please see my Code below

```
func storeVisitedContact(generic: Generic)
{
    let def = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var readArray : [Generic] = []

    if var testArray = def.objectForKey(constants.defaultsKeys.VISITED_CONTACTS_KEY) as? [Generic] {

       // readArray = testArray! as! [Generic]



        if testArray.count>=constants.defaultsKeys.VISITED_CONTACTS_COUNT

        {

            testArray.removeFirst()

        }

        else{

            testArray.append(generic)

        }

        readArray = testArray

    }

    else{

        readArray.append(generic)

    }

    for person in readArray {

        print("\(person.genericCode), you have been unarchived")

    }

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let archivedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(readArray as [Generic]) //Having an error here

    defaults.setObject(archivedObject, forKey: constants.defaultsKeys.VISITED_CONTACTS_KEY)
    defaults.synchronize()

}
```

**//ERROR 
--------------**

53496, you have been unarchived

```
 2016-05-11 18:19:06.931 ContactPLUS[1913:1025712] -[ContactPLUS.Generic
```

encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x148902d00
2016-05-11 18:19:06.933 ContactPLUS[1913:1025712] *** Terminating app due to   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ContactPLUS.Generic    encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x148902d00'

```
   *** First throw call stack:
   (0x180c3ae38 0x18029ff80 0x180c41ccc 0x180c3ec74 0x180b3cd1c 0x181586b80      0x181588034 0x181586b80 0x18158d9e8 0x100103a44 0x1000fee68 0x1000ff1b8   0x185ebbc5c 0x185f7977c 0x186036fd8 0x186044990 0x185d764a4 0x180bf07b0 0x180bee554 0x180bee984 0x180b18d10 0x182400088 0x185dedf70 0x100128f44    0x1806b68b8)
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Looks like something is expected to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol...

Comment: @trojanfoe, Could you pls tell me how to implement the NSCoding protocol in view controller?

Comment: Its done thanks...

Comment: Generic should conform to NSCoding protocol. Update your Generic class.